# Scroll spy not working in React. I tried several libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, navigation, scrollspy

I wanted to make a scroll spy navigation. I tried to use `react-scroll` and `react-ui-scrollspy` libraries but these libraries don't work for me I've also attached the picture.

[This is the image of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amos1.png)

It's the code of the right top reading panel which you can see in the picture:

```
<div className="reading-pane" style={{ overflow: 'auto' }}>
            {selected && !isSearchingForMembers && (
                <nav className="scrollspry_block" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                    <div className="flex_row_no-margin-bottom scrollspy-direct-url">
                        {topics.map((topic, index) => {
                            return (
                                <a onClick={() => setCurrent(index)} href={`#${topic.href}`} className={`scrollspry__button w-button ${index === current && 'w--current'}`}>
                                    {topic.title}
                                </a>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            )}
```

When I am scrolling it's not working even though I tried several libraries for it. Is there any idea what could be the problem that is causing this I imported CSS from Webflow CSS is nested so it's happening because of the CSS not sure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.